# vector space question?

Tags: linear-algebra

If the sum of the "vectors" $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is defined to be the function $f(g(x))$, then the "zero vector" is $g(x) = x$. Keep the usual scalar multiplication $cf(x)$ and find two rules that are broken.

The solution is: If $(f+g)(x)$ is the usual $f(g(x))$ then $(g+f)x$ is $g(f(x))$ which is different. Rule 4 is broken because there might be no inverse function $f^{−1}(x)$ such that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$.  If the inverse function exists it will be the vector $−f$.

I don't understand. There is no unique vector $-x$ such that $x + (-x) = 0$. Why the solution discussed inverse function?

[image]

Comment: The question is:  "Consider the space of functions (I guess they mean real valued functions of real numbers, or something like that.  Call it $S$.  We define a binary operation on $S$ by composition.  Is that operation invertible?  That is, given a function $f$, can we find a function $g$ such that $f\circ g(x)=x$ for all $x$?"

Comment: Should say:  this is not a vector space question.  The binary operation, composition, is not commutative so this could never be vector addition.

Comment: This structure is a *group* if we only take invertible functions, and a *monoid* otherwise.

Comment: @lulu I update my question. It's a question from vector space section in a linear algebra textbook.

Comment: I don't see what the edits contribute.  Yes, those are the defining properties of a vector space.  Again, this space is obviously not a vector space (using composition as the binary operation) since, generally, $f\circ g \neq g\circ f$ and vector addition must be commutative.  But, the question has little to do with vector spaces.  Instead, you are asked to find a function $f(x)$ which does not have a right inverse.  That is, a function $f(x)$ for which you can not find a function $g(x)$ such that $f\circ g(x)=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, the question asks to find two broken rules. One broken rule is number 1, commutative. The other broken rule is number 4. The solution used inverse to justify that 4th rule is violated, which I didn't understand why inverse function is involved in 4th rule.

Comment: Because property $4$ specifically concerns inverses.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of a vector space $V$ over a field $k$, we have two operations.  One is usually called "addition" (defined on pairs of elements of the vector space) and the other is usually called "scalar multiplication" (defined between one element of the field and one element of the vector space).  There are then a number of properties which define the way these operations must work such that the definition "makes sense" and also encompasses all the things which we consider intuitively to be vector spaces (such as $\mathbb{R}^n$), as well as more general and abstract things (such as vector spaces whose "vectors" are functions, polynomials, etc.).  This question asks you to show that the proposed definition of "addition" as function composition causes problems.

With respect to the "addition" operation, let's be more general and replace $+$ with $\star$, where the $\star$ symbol just means any operation that we'd like.  For a function $\star$ to work, there's a requirement that it be a binary operation $\star:V\times V\to V$ such that the following four properties hold:

1. **(identity)** There exists some $e\in V$ such that $e\star v = v\star e = e$ for all $v\in V$;
2. **(associative)** For all $u,v,w\in V$, we have $(u\star v)\star w = u\star (v\star w)$.
3. **(inverses exist)** For all $v\in V$, there exists $w\in V$ such that $v\star w=e$.
4. **(commutative)** For all $u,v\in V$, we have $u\star v=v\star w$.

When we use the usual $+$ notation for our binary operation, we write $-v$ for the inverse of $v\in V$.  If we use function composition, $\circ$, for our binary operation, we write $f^{-1}$ for the inverse of $f\in V$.

Does our proposed definition work for the vector space $V$ of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?  Let's check:

1. **(identity)** If we define $e:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $x\mapsto x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, this function satisfies the definition of an identity element (check this!)
2. **(associative)** If $f,g,h\in V$, then $(f\circ g)\circ h= f\circ(g\circ h)$ (again, check this!)
3. **(inverses exist)** Ahhh now we see why the question gives the hint... does every real-valued function of a real variable have an inverse?

So, to solve the problem, demonstrate a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which has no inverse.  This violates property $(3)$ above, and therefore the proposed definition does not satisfy the requirements of a vector space.

Comment: thank you. but can you explain "3.(inverses exist)"?  what does v star w =e mean? how to interpret e?

Comment: This is just part of the definition, so don't think about it as anything more than a set of requirements which we use to determine if some proposed "thing" is a vector space.

The expression $v\star w = e$ means that there exists a "neutral element" in $V$ under $\star: V\times V\to V$.  If we take $\star = +$, this means there's an element $0\in V$ such that $0 + v = v + 0 = v$ for all $v\in V$.  In other words, there's an element in this set which "does nothing."

Comment: ThANK you. But If you go back to my question, you will find you are talking about rule 3.But I am asking you about rule 4.

Comment: Yao, I've numbered them differently above.  My rule 3 and the textbook's rule 4 are the same thing.  But let's not get hung up on the numbering.  The question requires you to demonstrate a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is NOT invertible.  Can you think of a function like this?

Comment: First, may I ask why the question require me to demonstrate a function which is not invertible? I think this is my real confusion. What invertible play a role in the question? The rule 1-8 do not mention invertible at all. For rule 4, I can feel that addition and subtraction are invertible operation with each other. That is what I see the invertible.

Comment: When we defined function composition as our binary operation, we changed the definition of "inverse."  When the binary operation is $+$, the inverse is the negative value of the element.  When we use function composition, the inverse is the inverse of the function.  We're showing that this is not in fact a vector space by showing that inverses don't always exist, thus violating one of our criteria for a vector space.  You need to recognize that the notation $-v$ only makes sense if we define the operation to be addition.  The $-$ symbol is just short-hand for "inverse of" in additive notation.

Comment: x+(-x)=0 Is this 0 special? My logic is that we need (-x) to return any input to zero. Is this right?

Comment: Hi Yao, that is not correct.  The "neutral element" in this example is NOT $0\in\mathbb{R}$.  It is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Elements of this set are functions.  I recommend you look at examples of vector spaces besides the usual $\mathbb{R}^n$.  For example, it would be a useful exercise for you to prove that the set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space, where the binary operation is defined to be addition of polynomials, and the neutral element is the zero-polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Here the sum of vectors $f$ and $g$ is defined as function composition:

$$f + g \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} g \circ f$$

and the null vector is the identity function $id : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But then the existence of an element $-x$ such that $x + (-x) = 0$ is equivalent to asking for a function $x_1$ such that $x_1 \circ x = id$. Such a function only exists if $x$ is an invertible function.

Comment: Why $+(−)=0$ means inverse?